# node js : percentage based string compare

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to compare 2 address in node js

For ex: 2 address

```
1)  100 MAIN ST,   PO BOX 1022, SEATTLE WA 98104,   USA
2) 101 MAIN ST,   PO BOX 1022, SEATTLE WA 98104,   USA
```

should be treat as different address, but if we have

```
1)  100 MAIN ST,   PO BOX 1022, SEATTLE WA 98104,   USA
2) 100 MAIN ST,   PO BOX 1022, SEATTLA WA 98104,   USA
```

should be treat as same address, and i need to throw error. Anyone have any idea how to do this.? is there any function in node js to accomplish this? Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) might help you here. There's an [NPM package](https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein) that will do it for you

Comment: If it's only white-spaces you differ by, why not remove them all then compare?

Comment: Try to show what you have already done.

Comment: Are the whitespace and the 'A' in SEATTLA the (intended) diff you are looking for, besides 100 vs. 101? What do you mean by 'percentage'? (Since 0/1, E/A are both one char diff...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for how successful this might be in practice, but you might consider looking into string comparison algorithms. In particular, algorithms that measure a 'distance' between two strings to see how similar they are.

One is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Obviously you'd need to check this on a per-word basis and also be smart enough to know when you're looking at a house name or number (i.e. only consider words in the address that can tolerate typos).